# On checkout page spinner spins continuously and unable to do checkout process

Tags: magento2.2

On checkout page spinner spins continuously and unable to do checkout process

I have used magento 2.2 and created custom theme

In my theme i have magento_theme, web, media, etc folders and composer.json, theme.xml and registration.php files.

Can anybody help me.

Comment: Some errors in javascript occured and that stopped loaders to hide.

Comment: Thank you for reply. Yes there is issue with JS but not sure how to fix it. Can you please check the URL.
http://104.37.185.20/~sukottoscissors/

http://104.37.185.20/~sukottoscissors/checkout/cart/

Answer (score 0):

In what mode is your magento app running? As far as I can see there is a whole lot of js files that cannot be loaded which yield in observable results. Also on the rest of pages there are bugs like with minicart. Regerdless of what the answer is you could try to

```
rm -rf var/*
rm -rv pub/view/static/*
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Also, what is the server you are using? Do you have properly configured vhost? In case of nginx there is a sample configuration in app's root

Comment: I have already set 'MAGE_MODE' => 'developer' in app/etc/env.php file
Yes lots of js files are not loading, Yes on rest pages also i am having issue of js files
As per the magento doc i have created custom theme and apply it but when i apply it only broken layout displayed on browser. i have created child theme using parent Luma. So i basically i want to know that how to fix the js  issues and how to override the theme.

Comment: I am using this server
http://104.37.185.20/~sukottoscissors/phpinfo.php

Comment: I don't know about vhost configuration.

Comment: If luma works then the config is ok I suppose. What is the result of command: php bin/magento deploy:mode:show ? And, did you run my commands? The awkward thing is that I can open all the requested files.

Comment: I will run those commands and get back to you. However i have followed these tutorial
https://www.cloudways.com/blog/create-custom-theme-magento-2-part-1/ and created theme. Once theme created i just added my own css, js and images and added home page content and header, footer that's it. But rest of the pages and functions are not working.

Comment: This tutorial is ok, but you might have done something wrong in your custom files but that will be difficult for me to discover remotely. Also, it does not look for me that the files you overrode might have such an impact, eh ;/

Comment: I will get back to you once i run those commands, i think these commands we need to run when we created theme. Which i missed and that is why it doesn't reflect the default js and css etc.

Comment: I ran all these commands
rm -rf var/*
rm -rv pub/view/static/*
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
I received error
https://screenshot.net/ow83ms6

Comment: That explains everything. You are in default mode. Switch to developer mode with php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer, then repeat steps. And do not reindex. Indices are not connected with your problem at all.

Comment: Okay i will do it and update you. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Ok i ran this command : php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer
and developer mode get set.
And also repeat the steps
rm -rf var/* 
rm -rv pub/view/static/* 
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
still not loading default js

Comment: Screenshot: https://screenshot.net/kv4yyck

Comment: Can anybody help me?